# sitemap in asp.net

Tags: c#-3.0

can you please provide me the links for implementing sitemaps in asp.net c#

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=sitemap+asp.net

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the MSDN docs first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab(v=VS.85).aspx

http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/navigation/sitemappath.aspx

hth.